# ul in li , tree display with jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a object of object of object ... i have a tree !

i use this jade code for display my tree :

```
mixin file_list(files)
ul
    each file, i in files
        li #{file.id}
        if file.children.length > 0
            mixin file_list(file.children)
```

but the result is:

```
<ul>
    <li></li>
    <ul>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</ul>
```

i need :

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mixin file_list(files)
ul
    each file, i in files
        li #{file.id}
            if file.children.length > 0
                mixin file_list(file.children)
```