# print specific result from database in jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pug

My `app.js` code is :

```
for (var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
    data['result'][i] = {company_name: result[i].company_name};
}
res.render('findcompany', {data: data});
console.log(data);
```

result of `console.log(data)` is

```
{result:[{company_name:'a'},{company_name:'b'}]}
```

and `findcompany.pug` code is

```
doctype html

html

    include ./head

    body
        ul #{data}
```

but when i run this,i get

```
[object Object]
```

please help me, I am stuck here.

Comment: I think you have missing code to print li's. . This might help .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18483956/ul-in-li-tree-display-with-jade

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do loop on it like:

```
ul
  each val in data.result
    li= val.company_name
```